# Syntax for importing methods of type classes

Tags: haskell, syntax, module, typeclass

I noticed that GHC doesn't complain if I import (or export) the methods of type classes directly:

```
import Prelude (signum)
```

as opposed to using the "constructor" syntax:

```
import Prelude (Num(signum))
```

Because of this, I assumed that the former syntax was OK and went with it.  However, I ran into this odd issue with `fromInteger`, where the former syntax doesn't work -- GHC will accept it silently, only to complain later that `fromInteger` was never exported in the first place.  Did I happen to stumble upon some unspecified behavior in the language?

Here's a minimal test case:

```
-- A.hs
module A (fromInteger) where
import Prelude (fromInteger)

-- B.hs
module B where
import Prelude ()
import A
f = fromInteger
```

Comment: Both forms work fine for me on GHC 7.6.3 (at least in GHCi with `-XNoImplicitPrelude`, what version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @bheklilr Same version.